# Find the install location of brew on OS X

Tags: bash, homebrew

I'm creating a BASH scrip which requires a couple of applications to be installed. `ffmpeg` and `sox`

To ensure they are in place when my script runs I first check for the installation of Homebrew with :

```
#!/bin/bash
which -s brew
if [[ $? != 0 ]] ; then
    # Install Homebrew
    /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
fi
```

Then I check that `sox` and `ffmpeg` are installed with :

```
echo "---- checking for sox ----"
which -s sox || /usr/local/bin/brew install sox

echo "---- checking for ffmpeg ----"
which -s ffmpeg || /usr/local/bin/brew install ffmpeg
```

The problem I am facing is when Homebrew is installed but in a non-standard location.

I have to use the full path to Homebrew because this script is being run within [Playtypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus).

So the question is : How can I reliably get the installed path of Homebrew in a BASH script?

Comment: Can't you just catch the stdout of the `which` and grep/awk/regex on it's result? :) Or just pipe it directly

Comment: Yes, but that produced errors messages to be displayed in my scrip.You gave me inspiration however. See my answer below.

Comment: Are you using something like `var=$(which -s brew)` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering my own question...

You can test the output of `which brew` and deal with things accordingly. To gracefully deal with the case where Homebrew is not installed you can use `if which brew 2> /dev/null` which redirects `stderr` to `/dev/null`.

`brew --prefix` is also useful here as it give the path to where Homebrew installed applications are symlinked to, rather than their actual install path.

A script which works and shows this working :

```
#!/bin/bash
if which brew 2> /dev/null; then
    brewLocation=`which brew`
    appLocation=`brew --prefix`
    echo "Homebrew is installed in $brewLocation"
    echo "Homebrew apps are run from $appLocation"
else
   echo "Can't find Homebrew"
   echo "To install it open a Terminal window and type :"
   echo /usr/bin/ruby -e \"\$\(curl\ \-fsSL\ https\:\/\/raw\.github\.com\/Homebrew\/homebrew\/go\/install\)\"
fi
```

Thanks to [Allendar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1467267/allendar%29%20for%20the%20pointers.) for the pointers.

Comment: Thanks! a shame that its undocumented in `brew --help`

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to this, Homebrew's `--prefix` mode has been enhanced here in the far-flung future of 2020 (or maybe it was always this way), so that it now takes a package name as an argument. Meaning locating those "keg-only" packages which aren't linked into standard paths is as easy as:

```sh
$ brew --prefix ffmpeg
/usr/local/opt/ffmpeg
```